# underscore.js: _.pick to extract properties inside an object that's in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Below is the object that I have:

```
{
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "id": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "createdAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
  "Details": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "token": null,
      "deviceId": null,
      "code": 12345678,
      "verified": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
      "UserEmail": "joe@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am hoping to use the [pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) method from the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) library and return the following object:

```
{
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "token": null,
      "deviceId": null,
      "code": 12345678,
      "verified": null,
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using:

```
var modifiedObj = _.pick(obj, 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName');
```

which returns:

```
{
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null
}
```

How do I extract the `Details` object and only some of the `properties` inside it?

Comment: You can pass custom function to _.pick instead of prop names. Or even better try http://vanilla-js.com instead of underscore.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than picking at multiple levels, I'd just do

```js
var obj = {
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "id": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "createdAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
  "Details": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "token": null,
      "deviceId": null,
      "code": 12345678,
      "verified": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T18:16:07.000Z",
      "UserEmail": "joe@example.com"
    }
  ]
};

var newObj = (({email, firstName, lastName, Details}) =>
  ({
    email, 
    firstName, 
    lastName,
    Details: Details.map(
     ({token, deviceId, code, verified}) => ({token, deviceId, code, verified}))
  })
)(obj);

console.log(newObj);
```

In this pattern, we "pick" using ES6 parameter destructuring by writing a function to which we pass an object, and extract the properties we want from that object right in the parameter list, with the `({p1, p2}) =>` syntax. Then, for the function's return value, we specify a new object containing just those properties, using object literal shorthand, which allows us to just write `{p1, p2}` to get the equivalent of `{p1: p1, p2: p2}`. So the simplest case, to pick properties `p1` and `p1`, would be

```
(({p1, p2}) => ({p2, p2}))(obj)
```

In the above example, we use this pattern once at the top level, then again to pick from each element of the `Details` array, via `map`.

Of course, if you really wanted to, or thought the above was too confusing, you could always pick "manually":

```
var newObj = {
  email: obj.email,
  ...,
  Details: obj.Details.map(function(detail) {
    return {token: detail.token, ...};
  })
};
```

#### Using `_.pick`

If you still want to use `_.pick`, then you need to do it twice:

```
var newObj = _.pick(obj, 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'Details');
obj.Details = _.map(obj.Details, function(detail) {
  return detail.pick('token', ...);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this can work

```
var modifiedObj = _.pick(obj, 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName','Details[0].token','Details[0].deviceId','Details[0].code','Details[0].verified');
```

Comment: Could you make this into an executable snippet to show how it works?